# Hibernate Mapping OneToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities that I have a unique issue with.

entity A can contain a single entity B
entity B can contain a single entity A (but not the one above)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITYA")
public class EntityA {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Long entityAId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entityAId", nullable = true)
    private EntityB entityB;

    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITYB")
public class EntityB {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long entityBId;
    private Long officeId;
    private Long name;

    @OneToOne
    private EntityA entityA;
}
```

I don't think this is a bidirectional relationship, the entityA on entityB is different object.   When I do a search and get EntityA back, I get a EntityB, that contains a EntityA with all null attributes.  I don't know the proper mapping (or even terminology it would seem) for how to do this. I get a StackOverflow when the entities are trying to be retrieved from the search.

Here is a textual description that might make more sense. A Patient (EntityA) has one Person (EntityB) that is responsible for them. That Person can contain one of type Patient (EntityA). So A points to B, which has a reference to another A.

Comment: Think about whether the entity you're looking up results in a cyclical reference. Will you find yourself in a case where EntityA fetches EntityB, which fetches EntityA, which fetches EntityB, etc continuing forever? Because that would certainly cause a StackOverflow.

Comment: I think you are missing the mappedBy attribute in the @OneToOne from EntityB side (mappedBy value should be the name of the property in EntityA which references EntityB). You need that in order to make it bidirectional.

Comment: @ChrisFei - I think that is exactly what is going on.  However, I am not sure if there is a way to solve this other than not having EntityB have a reference to EntityA.  That would be the ideal solution, but perhaps its not technically possible?

Comment: @frandiaz83, I think the mappedBy attribute is only on the "parent" class, in this case it would be on EntityA.  But I could be wrong too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you need two entities?

Let's imagine next situation:

1) An employee can have only one supervisor. The supervisor can be responsible for only one employee. Supervisor is an employee.

2) Supervisor is also being supervised by another employee.

This gives us only one entity and one self-targeted relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "SUPERVISOR", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private Employee supervisor;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy="supervisor") 
  private Employee responsibility;
  ...
}
```

Also I suggest you to analyze if the relationships are indeed OneToOne which is a rare occasion in real world. In my example the relationship could easily be ManyToOne/OneToMany with employee supervising multiple other employees.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "SUPERVISOR", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private Employee supervisor;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="supervisor") 
  private List<Employee> responsibilities;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems much cleaner.  And I think you are correct about the ManyToOne just in case one becomes responsible later for more than one.